# How to change the default comment window size in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make the comment window size to be 800x600 as default. How can I do that? Do I need VBA?

Note: I don't have VBA experience

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can set the comment size universally. It must be done manually.

Using VBA you can resize the default comment box using a scale factor. Here I double the size using `2`

```
Sub SizeComments()
    Dim cmt As Comment

    For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
        With cmt.Shape
            .ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        End With
    Next cmt
End Sub
```

I don't know of any way to directly set the size as per your request e.g. 800 x 600.

Note that each time you run this code the comment boxes grow in size so might be something you run once only.